# Can't do a mob invisible trick

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hello I'm trying to do a command that makes a Mob invisible to you but not invisible to other players I tried to do it with some sort of command that used 100 command blocks but all that did was crash my my game. I also tried making the mob flicker but all that did was make it invisible. :l

Comment: Could you give more details on how you attempted to make the mobs invisible and/or flicker? If it's really 100 command blocks, a link to the site giving the instructions should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish similar using scoreboard teams:

[image: Image comparing what a player on the same team as an invisible creeper sees vs a player not on the same team as an invisible creeper]

Players on the same team as an invisible mob will see the invisible mob as semi-transparent, whereas players on a different team (or not on any team) will not see the mob at all.

---

To do this, create a team:

```
/scoreboard teams add SeeMobs
```

Then add the mob and everyone except you to the team:

```
/scoreboard teams join SeeMobs @e[type=???,r=???] @a[rm=1]
```

Then add the invisibility effect to the mob:

```
/effect @e[type=???,r=???] minecraft:invisibility 1000000 0 true
```

Replace `@e[type=???,r=???]` with however you're identifying the mob.